# Removing extra pixels/lines from license plate

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, tesseract, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I am using HOG feature detector based on SVM classification. I can successfully extract license plate, but the extracted number plate have some unnecessary pixels/lines apart from license number. My image processing pipeline is as follows:

1. Applying HOG detector on the grayscale image
2. Cropping detected region
3. Re-sizing the cropped image
4. Applying adaptive threshold to highlight the plate numbers & filtering background using following **Opencv** code

   ```
   cvAdaptiveThreshold(cropped_plate, thresholded_plate, 255,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV,11, 9);
   ```
5. De-skewing plate image

Due to this unnecessary information, ***Tesseract-OCR*** software is getting confused to recognize numbers correctly. The extracted number plates images look like the following.

[image]     [image]

How can i filter these unnecessary pixels/lines from the images? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What about erode-dilate? How about removing small contour?

Comment: A bit more examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove all non-text objects in the image. To do that, I suggest sorting the blobs by area of their bounding box (maxy - miny)*(maxx - minx). Do some statistical analysis; you know you are looking for objects of a similar size. Once you identify the approximate size of a character, make a larger bounding box that estimates the whole text. Keep the small blobs inside it, so for your picture, the dash sign will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve a lot by filtering contours out. Try to find contours that have a certain width/height ratio, a certain amount of white pixels with [`countNonZero()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) etc. If that does not help, you can always try to implement a text detection algorithm like [Run Length Smoothing Algorithm](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1295359) (RLSA).